# How to count the last 30 day occurrence & transpose a column's row value to new columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get the count of occurrence of the status column for each 'name', 'id' & 'branch' combination  in the last 30 days using Pyspark.

For simplicity lets assume the current day is 19/07/2021

**Input dataframe**

```
id name branch     status eventDate
1  a    main       failed 18/07/2021
1  a    main       error  15/07/2021
2  b    main       failed 16/07/2021
3  c    main       snooze 12/07/2021
4  d    main       failed 18/01/2021
2  b    main       failed 18/07/2021
```

**expected output**

```
id name branch     failed error snooze 
1  a    main       1      1     0
2  b    main       2      0     0
3  c    main       0      0     1
4  d    main       0      0     0
```

I tried the following code.

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F
    df = df.withColumn("eventAgeinDays", (F.datediff(F.current_timestamp(), F.col("eventDate"))))
    df = df.groupBy('id', 'branch', 'name', 'status')\
           .agg(
            F.sum(
                F.when(F.col("eventAgeinDays") <= 30, 1).otherwise(0)
            ).alias("Last30dayFailure")
    )
    df = df.groupBy('id', 'branch', 'name', 'status').pivot('status').agg(F.collect_list('Last30dayFailure'))
```

The code kind of gives me the output, but I get arrays in the output since I am using `F.collect_list()`

my partially correct output

```
id name branch     failed error snooze 
1  a    main       [1]     [1]    []
2  b    main       [2]     []     []
3  c    main       []      []     [1]
4  d    main       []      []     []
```

Could you please suggest a more elegant way of creating my ***expected output***? Or let me know how to fix my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `collect_list` which creates list, use `first` as the aggregation method (*The reason we can use `first` is that you already had an aggregation grouped by `id`, `branch`, `name` and `status` so you are sure that there's at most one value for each unique combination*):

```
(df.groupBy('id', 'branch', 'name')
   .pivot('status')
   .agg(F.first('Last30dayFailure'))
   .fillna(0)
   .show())

+---+------+----+-----+------+------+
| id|branch|name|error|failed|snooze|
+---+------+----+-----+------+------+
|  1|  main|   a|    1|     1|     0|
|  4|  main|   d|    0|     0|     0|
|  3|  main|   c|    0|     0|     1|
|  2|  main|   b|    0|     2|     0|
+---+------+----+-----+------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working. Thanks for the explanation as well!